# How to make Django tree view

Tags: django, treeview

[image]`html`

I tried to make a tree of accounts, but the parent is repeated for every child

```
{% for acc in accs %}
        <ul class="tree" id="tree">
            <li>
                <details>
                    <summary>{{acc.acc_id1}}  {{acc.E_name1}} </summary>
                        <ul>
                            <details>
                                <summary> {{acc.acc_id2}} {{acc.E_name2}}</summary>
                                    <ul>
                                        <details>
                                            <summary>{{acc.acc_id3}} {{acc.E_name3}}</summary>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>{{acc.acc_id4}} {{acc.E_name4}}</li>
                                                </ul>
                                        </details>
                                    </ul>
                            </details>
                        </ul>
                       </details>
            </li>
        </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Mainacc (models.Model):
    acc_id1 = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    E_name1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    A_name1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.acc_id1}  {self.E_name1}'

class Aacc (models.Model):
    acc_id1 = models.ForeignKey(Mainacc, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    acc_id2 = models.IntegerField( db_index=True, unique=True)
    E_name2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    A_name2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return f' {self.acc_id2}  {self.E_name2}'

    
class Bacc (models.Model):
    acc_id2 = models.ForeignKey(Aacc, on_delete =models.CASCADE)
    acc_id3 = models.IntegerField( db_index=True, unique=True)
    E_name3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    A_name3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return f' {self.acc_id3}  {self.E_name3}'
    
class Cacc (models.Model):
    acc_id3 = models.ForeignKey(Bacc, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    acc_id4 = models.BigIntegerField( db_index=True, unique=True)
    E_name4 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    A_name4 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return f' {self.acc_id4}  {self.E_name4}'
```

views.py

```
def Acc(request):
    mainacc_list = Mainacc.objects.all()
    aacc_list = Aacc.objects.all()
    bacc_list = Bacc.objects.all()
    cacc_list = Cacc.objects.all()
    acc_list = list(chain(mainacc_list, aacc_list,bacc_list,cacc_list))
    return render (request,'templates\\acc\\acc.html',{'accs':acc_list})
```